# Cert error connecting to AWS DocumentDB from Docker C# app

Tags: c#, mongodb, aws-documentdb

My .net Core app works and connects fine from my host machine.

Once built and run from a docker container it fails with error `System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`

The mongo connection string used `mongodb://user@xxxx.amazonaws.com/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false&connectTimeoutMS=3000`

I've verified the cert file is in the directory with the rest of my binaries when the app is run using `RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem -P /app`

I've also tried to install the cert using the `dotnet-certificate-tool` within the container.

Update: I was able to get the p7b version of the cert to work but it had to be loaded via code. It could not be loaded from the OS cert store.

Comment: Can you use your C# code (without username,pw etc.) that I can use to repro? Also did you follow the code sample from here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html?

Comment: @meet-bhagdev Looks like .Net running under Linux can't load certs from the Linux cert store. In Windows the cert will load from the OS without any special code. In Linux however you have to load it via code. I'll update this once I figure out more

Answer (score 1):

Same issue using Net core 6 web api deployed to docker Debian GNU/Linux 11 with error message: `A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server...tldr;cut;tldr;...Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.\n ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain\n...tldr;cut;...`

And solved by adding some lines in Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

# add AWS RDS CA bundle
ADD https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem /tmp/rds-ca/aws-rds-ca-bundle.pem
# split the bundle into individual certs (prefixed with xx)
# see http://blog.swwomm.com/2015/02/importing-new-rds-ca-certificate-into.html
RUN cd /tmp/rds-ca && cat aws-rds-ca-bundle.pem|awk 'split_after==1{n++;split_after=0} /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1} {print > "cert" n ""}' \
    && for CERT in /tmp/rds-ca/cert*; do mv $CERT /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aws-rds-ca-$(basename $CERT).crt; done \
    && rm -rf /tmp/rds-ca \
    && update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
...
...
```